# Replacing an existing HTML element?

Tags: javascript, php, html

currently I am trying to replace a simple HTML element to alert the user that the password/username they have entered does not exist. I'm new to programming and I'm not sure what I'm doing is not working simply because it does not work or because I've made and error somewhere.

Here is the Php code excerpt:

```
if($player['id'] == false)
echo "
<script>
document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='That username does not exist.'; 
</script>
";
```

And then farther down I have this in HTML:

```
<p id="alert">Enter your Username and Password Above.</p>
```

I'm trying to replace the "Enter your Username" part with the "username does not exist" bit. Is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: Servers won't interact with the client once the page is loaded unless you use begin a new connection via something like ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best way to implement this is

make your message like this

```
$message = "Enter your Username and Password Above.";

if($player['id'] == false){
   $message = "That username does not exist.";
}
```

and use it in html

```
<p id="alert"><?php echo $message; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
    document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='That username does not exist.'; 
</script>
```

I guess it is because your have not defined the type of your script
may be you could try the code above

**Update**
For your information, if you ask javascript looking for an element by ID, you need to make sure the element is exist, therefore, you need to put the above script under the html element with id "alert"

Answer (score 0):

This should work. But I was not able to test this.

```
<?php if($player['id'] == false) { ?>
 <script type='text/javascript'>  
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='That username does not exist.'; 
 </script>
<?php } ?>
```